# what is the hardware configuration required for the mac os 10.5.8 and mac os 10.6.2

Tags: macos, iphone, sdk

i am having mac mini with mac os 10.4.11, with 512mb of ram and now i want to install the iphone sdk 3.2  but it is giving me error that it requir mac os 10.6.2. 
can i install mac os 10.6.2 with my old mac mini hardware configuration.

Comment: It depends on whether your Mac Mini is Intel or PowerPC. In the former case the answer is yes (but get more RAM), in the latter case it's no.

Answer (score 1):

Let Apple be your guide: http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html

Comment: And btw - for comparison: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3759

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26562/leopardassist if you're having issues installing snow leopard on an old intel mac. If the computer is ppc (PowerPC) your out of luck.

Comment: Leopard Assist is to help with installing 10.5 on older PPCs.
There is no need for a tool to help install 10.6 on older Intels, because all Intel Macs are supported already.

Comment: That's not quite true, some of the initial macbook didn't meet the specs to run snow leopard. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook

Comment: @Kendall - all MacBooks can run 10.6, although they may not have originally shipped with enough RAM. 10.6 requires any Intel processor and 1GB RAM; and all Intel Macs can be upgraded to 2GB at least.

Answer (score 1):

10.6.2 installs onto any Intel Mac, and 10.5.8 Installer claims to require anything faster than a 867MHz G4 and 512MB of RAM, although it will technically run on less.

Comment: But the OP wishes to run the iPhone SDK, which requires an Intel processor.

Comment: I was answering the letter of the question if perhaps not the spirit. :)